# get the data which are partially filled data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have table `output` data are

```
id  q1_ans     q2_ans     q3_ans
1.  '100'     'Nokia'     'abc'
2.            'IPhone'    'def'
3.  '300'     'Samsung'   'ahk'
4.  ''        ''          ''
```

I required only partially filled data like data of id '2'

Comment: Table input data might be more useful

Comment: is that the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select q1_ans, q2_ans, q3_ans FROM table WHERE 
    q1_ans='' OR q2_ans='' OR q3_ans='' 
    AND NOT (q1_ans='' AND q2_ans='' AND q3_ans='');
```

Comment: if i use `select *` instead of `select q1_ans, q2_ans, q3_ans` it shows all values when i test

Comment: there is code :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2809/1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table`
    WHERE 
    q1_ans = '' AND q2_ans = '' AND q3_ans = ''
    AND NOT (q1_ans='' AND q2_ans='' AND q3_ans='');
```

Comment: thanx for reply, i want to find partially data using fields q1_ans,q2_ans,q3_ans and not with id because i want to find incomplete field like id '2'

Comment: but this will also show all incomplete field like id '4'.  i want that column in which some are filled and some are blank

Comment: sorry @Hassaan but i have q1_ans ,q2_ans,q3 .....ans_q15 field and this query not working perfect

Answer (score 0):

It works i tested

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE (`q1_ans`="" OR `q2_ans`="" OR `q3_ans`="") AND id NOT in(SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE `q1_ans`="" AND `q2_ans`="" AND `q3_ans`="")
```